# EC2 - High CPU and High Disk Reads - Crash

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu, disk-io

For some reason today my EC2 server keeps hitting 100% CPU and high disk reads. I've turned all of my cronjobs off, and yet it's still happening. My Database is an RDS outside the server. Any initial items I should check? I'm using PHP scripts for my cronjobs (8 seperate scripts that run anywhere from every 5 minutes to twice a day).

Both happen at the same time. I've also attached a screenshot of what shows when I run top.

[image: CPU load]

[image: Disk Reads]

[image: Top]

Comment: Are you using custom code only or your own code coupled with a framework? Also, try XDebug.

Comment: custom code only. I did find in the access logs that someone was trying to run the phpmyadmin setup script a bunch of times from different IPs. I ran yum remove phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is happening right now, run `top` to see if it is actually a PHP script: Maybe it's some other process.

If you can't catch it on the act, I suggest you set up `atop` to provide the same data in retrospect.

Comment: It's not happening this second, when it does start to happen the entire server becomes unresponsive and I can't even run top or ssh in. I have to manually reboot from the AWS console. I did find in the access logs that someone was trying to run the phpmyadmin setup script a bunch of times from different IPs. I ran yum remove phpmyadmin.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of Top

Comment: Yep, screenshot shows that httpd (apache) is taking up the CPU so it seems like there are URL-s that get hit which trigger a heavy load. You are under DoS attack my friend, try to figure out what URL-s are triggered from logs and block access to them or optimize the scripts behind these URLs/

Comment: Would you suggest installing mod_evasive?

Comment: You should trawl the logs to find out if there are any other vulnerabilities like the phpmyadmin. mod_evasive will not help if it only takes a few requests to kill the server.

Comment: Look for requests to your server before the crash (/var/log/httpd/*log).

Comment: it appears it might have something to do w/ the popularity of my app. I'm going to spin up another server and put it behind a load balancer